# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef(Link)`

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui

Our NextJS app works fine in prod, and locally it renders OK, but we get some ugly warnings I'm trying to quiet.

```
client.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef(Link)`. Expected an element type that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally provide a plain function component instead? For more information see https://mui.com/r/caveat-with-refs-guide
    at Link (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/material/Link/Link.js:111:83)
    at Link (webpack-internal:///./src/components/Link.tsx:29:11)
    at span[...]
```

`Link.tsx` looks like this:

```js
import { LinkProps, Link as MuiLink } from "@mui/material";
import NextLink, { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from "next/link";
// Defining the CustomNextLink
export type CustomNextLinkProps = Omit<NextLinkProps, "href"> & {
  _href: NextLinkProps["href"];
};
export const CustomNextLink = ({ _href, ...props }: CustomNextLinkProps) => {
  return <NextLink href={_href} {...props} />;
};
// combine MUI LinkProps with NextLinkProps
type CombinedLinkProps = LinkProps<typeof NextLink>;
// we remove both href properties
// and define a new href property using NextLinkProps
export type MyLinkProps = Omit<CombinedLinkProps, "href"> & {
  href: NextLinkProps["href"];
};
export const Link = ({ href, ...props }: MyLinkProps) => {
  // use _href props of CustomNextLink to set the href
  return <MuiLink {...props} component={CustomNextLink} _href={href} />;
};
```

I have a repro here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3ucqb2?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FLink.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Findex.tsx&title=React%20Starter

It seems whenever we use this  component the warning appears in the console. Other instances of this error seem to be resolve by wrapping inner components in a `<div>` or similar, but that doesn't seem to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ref isn't being forwarded properly in this custom Link component, which is usually the source of this error. Integrating Next's Link with Material UI's Link is kind of brutal honestly, so I always just use the official example from MUI which has no console errors: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs-pages-router-ts/src/Link.tsx

It looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import NextLink, { LinkProps as NextLinkProps } from 'next/link';
import MuiLink, { LinkProps as MuiLinkProps } from '@mui/material/Link';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

// Add support for the sx prop for consistency with the other branches.
const Anchor = styled('a')({});

interface NextLinkComposedProps
  extends Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, 'href'>,
    Omit<NextLinkProps, 'href' | 'as' | 'passHref' | 'onMouseEnter' | 'onClick' | 'onTouchStart'> {
  to: NextLinkProps['href'];
  linkAs?: NextLinkProps['as'];
}

export const NextLinkComposed = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, NextLinkComposedProps>(
  function NextLinkComposed(props, ref) {
    const {
      to,
      linkAs,
      replace,
      scroll,
      shallow,
      prefetch,
      legacyBehavior = true,
      locale,
      ...other
    } = props;

    return (
      <NextLink
        href={to}
        prefetch={prefetch}
        as={linkAs}
        replace={replace}
        scroll={scroll}
        shallow={shallow}
        passHref
        locale={locale}
        legacyBehavior={legacyBehavior}
      >
        <Anchor ref={ref} {...other} />
      </NextLink>
    );
  },
);

export type LinkProps = {
  activeClassName?: string;
  as?: NextLinkProps['as'];
  href: NextLinkProps['href'];
  linkAs?: NextLinkProps['as']; // Useful when the as prop is shallow by styled().
  noLinkStyle?: boolean;
} & Omit<NextLinkComposedProps, 'to' | 'linkAs' | 'href'> &
  Omit<MuiLinkProps, 'href'>;

// A styled version of the Next.js Link component:
// https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link
const Link = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(function Link(props, ref) {
  const {
    activeClassName = 'active',
    as,
    className: classNameProps,
    href,
    legacyBehavior,
    linkAs: linkAsProp,
    locale,
    noLinkStyle,
    prefetch,
    replace,
    role, // Link don't have roles.
    scroll,
    shallow,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = typeof href === 'string' ? href : href.pathname;
  const className = clsx(classNameProps, {
    [activeClassName]: router.pathname === pathname && activeClassName,
  });

  const isExternal =
    typeof href === 'string' && (href.indexOf('http') === 0 || href.indexOf('mailto:') === 0);

  if (isExternal) {
    if (noLinkStyle) {
      return <Anchor className={className} href={href} ref={ref} {...other} />;
    }

    return <MuiLink className={className} href={href} ref={ref} {...other} />;
  }

  const linkAs = linkAsProp || as;
  const nextjsProps = {
    to: href,
    linkAs,
    replace,
    scroll,
    shallow,
    prefetch,
    legacyBehavior,
    locale,
  };

  if (noLinkStyle) {
    return <NextLinkComposed className={className} ref={ref} {...nextjsProps} {...other} />;
  }

  return (
    <MuiLink
      component={NextLinkComposed}
      className={className}
      ref={ref}
      {...nextjsProps}
      {...other}
    />
  );
});

export default Link;
```

Hope that helps!